# Create Entity-Relationship Diagram from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, reverse-engineering, adodb, entity-relationship

I am trying to create an Entity-Relationship Diagram by reverse engineering a MySQL database using a .SQL file. The process has been successful, using MySQL WorkBench and Toad Data Modeler. However, the diagram that both tools generate does not show the relationships between entities. So the diagram is of little use.

Having asked the software's technical support team why this is so, the reply is that they have used ADODB as a database abstraction layer in order to support several DBMSs, and ADODB doesn't explicitly define foreign keys. My question is, is there a tool that can generate these relationships by making guesses related to column names etc.?

They also mention that they use an XML descriptor to view the database structure. So is it possible to generate a diagram from the XML document?

I would generally create the ERD myself, but the database contains 99 tables and would be an extremely tedious process.

Thanks a lot,
Amy

Answer (score 2):

Another is ERWin by CA. Its fanatastic tool to reverse and forward engineer databases and can infer relationships from column names. Its very costly though, i have used the trial version.

Comment: ERwin Data Modeler is available also in Community Edition for free. See http://erwin.com/products/detail/ca_erwin_data_modeler_community_edition/.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question:

In Toad Data Modeler, there is a function that infers the relationships between tables based on field names etc. In the Menu, it is under Macros -> All -> Infer Relationship.

I haven't checked that the relationships are completely accurate, but it appears to have worked well.

Thanks,
Amy